# SwapMouseButton does not "resist" a reboot

Tags: winapi

I am SwapMouseButton function to change the primary mouse button from right to left.

It seems work, the mouse buttons are swapped, and I can go check in the settings and see that they are indeed swapped...

BUT,

If I reboot the computer, the setting goes back to the original setting, undoing my programmatic swap.

Any clue as to what might be going wrong there?

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/857259/how-do-you-swap-the-primary-mouse-button-via-commandline-in-windows-8-without-a

Answer (score 0):

Swapping the mouse buttons via code is not a permanent operation. As you have already discovered, it is reset on the next OS restart.  If the user wants the buttons swapped permanently, they should be setting that in the Control Panel, not in your code.

That said, if you really want to handle this in code, then every time your app is run, have it use `GetSystemMetrics(SM_SWAPBUTTON)` to check if the mouse buttons are currently swapped, and if not then swap them.